# Remove www from HTTPS request in Nginx

Tags: https, nginx

I have the following code:

```
server {
listen 443;
server_name www.domain.com;

ssl on;
ssl_certificate    /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.com.crt;
ssl_certificate_key    /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.com.key;

return 301 https://domain.com$request_uri;
}
```

If I access `https://domain.com` everything works, if I access `https://www.domain.com` I get a SSL warning that the Certificate does not match the domain, which it doesn't. Once you accept the invalid SSL cert it redirects you to `https://domain.com` with the valid cert.

But if I remove the `ssl on;` bit etc, then neither `https://domain.com` or `https://www.domain.com` work.

So how can I remove the WWW without the SSL Invalid warning?

I only have an SSL cert for `domain.com` and not for `www.domain.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTPS is HTTP over in TLS/SSL connection. Before any HTTP transaction, the client must be verify server certificate through SSL-Handshake ritual. Your redirection, which is HTTP transaction, will be start after SSL-Handshake.

If you want `https://www.domain.com` redirect to `https://domain.com` without SSL Invalid warning, your certificate must be valid to both `domain.com` and `www.domain.com`.

The simplest way is ask your CA to append `www.domain.com` to [subjectAltName](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubjectAltName) field in your certificate, so you can serve multiple domain with one certificate. Some CAs will do it without cost. The other options is obtain new certificate for `www.domain.com` although it's pretty overkill.

Comment: Ah yes, was afraid of that. I have very limited time, hoped there was a coded way. Thanks :)

Comment: Ha, looks like my Host screwed up creating the SSL cert. It is supposed to cover www, but it didn't! They've giving me a new one free. :)